# Hooks Law and acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, potential-energy, spring, homework-and-exercises

A 435 gram sharpened piece of iron rebar into a spring loaded device. It
takes a force of 355 Newtons to compress the spring by 27.5 cm. With what speed does the
rebar shoot out of the device?

Relevant Formulas
F = kx (Hooks Law)
F = ma (Newtons 2nd Law)
$Pe =  {1 \over 2 } kx^2$

Mass = .435kg
Force = 355N
X = .275m

K = $ {F} \over X $ = $355N \over .275m$ = $1290.91$  $ N \over M $

Now that I have the spring constant, do I use Potential Energy? $ {1 \over 2 } kx^2$

Conservation of Energy..

$ K_i + U_i = K_f + U_f$

$ U_i = K_f $

$ {1 \over 2 }kx^2 = {1 \over 2}mv^2 $

Plug in the numbers?

$ {1 \over 2} (1290.9{N \over M})(.275m)^2 = {1 \over 2}(.435kg)v^2$

$97.62{N \over M^3} \over (.435kg)$ = $ v^2$ , $97.62{kg\cdot{m^2} \over s^2} \over (.435kg)$ = $ v^2$

$ V = 14.98 {m \over s} $

Comment: So what is _your_ question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but note that $U_i = K_f$ because $U_f$ is 0 and $K_i$ is 0. The rest of the working seems fine.

$ {1 \over 2 }kx^2 = {1 \over 2}mv^2 $

$ {1 \over 2} (1290.9{N \over M})(.275m)^2 = {1 \over 2}(.435kg)v^2$

but we know $N/m = kg/s^2$

$97.62{kg\cdot{m^2} \over s^2} \over (.435kg)$ = $ v^2$

You may have multiplied wrongly. $N/m * m^2 = N\cdot{m}$ and not $N/m^3$

Comment: I plugged in the numbers, but the units aren't working out..

Comment: @HarrisNghiem I've edited  my answer to include the working

Comment: Can you break down where we got $ K_i$ is zero? The whole idea still confuses me

Comment: $U_i \neq 0$. The spring is still depressed and there is elastic potential energy. But it is $U_f$ that is zero, because by then the spring is fully released and all the potential energy is converted to kinetic energy.